# HighChart for PHP 5.1 lower

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am new to PHP and Highchart. Currently, I am trying to:

**1.**  Query my data from MySQL using PHP.

**2.** To display `HighChart :: Javascript`, get data from `json_encode` in PHP.

**Problem now**, my PHP is 5.1.6 (I have a few applications running since few years back, try not to upgrade the php). I cannot use the **`json_numeric_check`**.

**Help Needed :**

Question 1: is there any alternative way to get the value without **`json_numeric_check`**?

Question 2: Is there any package I can add in to php 5.1.6 to use **`json_numeric_check`**?

This is the code I want to use ::

```
print json_encode($result,json_numeric_check);
```

**My Full Code**

```
<?php  
header("Content-Type:application/json");
include_once "shift.php";
list($s1,$e1,$shift) = shift_frame();
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = "";
$password = "";

$select = "SELECT EH_CELLNUM, COUNT(EH_SERIALID)";
$table = " FROM T_EEDATA";
$rule1 = " WHERE (EH_END_DT between ".$s1." and ".$e1.") group by EH_CELLNUM";
$conn = mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

mysql_select_db("eedata",$conn) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = $select.$table.$rule1;
$query = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

$category = array();
$category['name'] = 'Cellnum';
$series1 = array();
$series1['name'] = 'SerialID';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$category['data'][] = $row['EH_CELLNUM'];
$series1['data'][] = $row['COUNT(EH_SERIALID)'];
}

////////////code add here???/////////////////////////////

$result = array();
array_push($result,$category);
$result2 = array();
array_push($result,$series1);
print json_encode($result,json_numeric_check);

mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: I'm not an PHP expert, but in JS you can parse values. Like this `json[0] = $.map(json[0], function(item) {  return parseInt(item, 10); });` (of course, that code may not work right away, it depends on your current data format - if you can show generated data sample, then I can tweak snippet above).

Answer (score 0):

you can do someting to $result before json_encode
for example:

```js
$result = array("1", "2", "3", "4");
$result = array_str_to_int($result);

// only for simple array,you can optimize the code 
function array_str_to_int($array){
  $tmp_arr = array();
  foreach( $array as $k => $v ){
    $tmp_arr[] = intval($v);
  }
  return $tmp_arr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But the problem is after Json_encode(), all the int will be added double quotes.  highchart can not recognize the int and cause syntax error.

Comment: $result = array_str_to_int($result); The result is what?"[1,2,3,4]"?

Comment: hi suibber, let me clarify; I just edited and posted my full code in my question above. You are suggesting  "to do something, $result before json_encode" is it the location as I mentioned in my full code above?

Comment: use "var_dump($result);exit;" What is the result? (before print json_encode($result,json_numeric_check);)